# Op-amp application

Tags: operational-amplifier

How can I build a circuit which amplifies input signal one time per one second? I don't know  how to make it but I've just built a circuit below. It consists of integrator, adder and differentiator. Is it a correct circuit at this aim? I need help/advice building the right circuit. Can anyone help me about that?

Op-amps are ideal. No need to supply for op-amps.

Integrator circuit capacitance: 0.1μF, R = 10k, Rf = 100M

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a differentiator following an integrator?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "amplify a signal one time per second"? Are you trying to change the frequency of the signal? Or are you trying to sample the signal? Or are you trying to amplify the signal with a gain that changes over time?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called a "Sample & Hold Amplifier".

Comment: Do you mean your integrator (U1) need its capacitor resetting every second?